# ¿How to define the script interpreter Rundeck running over windows?

Tags: rundeck

I want to run a script in windows CMD and another one in Powershell, how can i define what interpreter use in the job step?

Can use gitBash (minTty) to run bash inside rundeck running over windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define any interpreter for your scripts, for example, for PowerShell scripts on your job go to Script Step, click on the "Advanced" button and define "powershell.exe" on the "Invocation String" textbox. That means that your script (inline or "external") must be interpreted by PowerShell.

Also works if you like to use cmd.exe, python2, python3, bash, or anything else (like minTty).

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#advanced-script-options).